# How to jump to an another line of code while executing an Android app

Tags: java, android

I want to know how to jump to an another line of code while executing an Android app.

**Here is my problem in detail.**

First of all, here is my code:-.

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener

            (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                 @Override

                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {







                         int Current_Song;

                         Songs song = Song.get(i);



                         //If mediaPlayer is not used before, this will make oldsong as present song.

                         if (Old_Song == -326523) {

                             Old_Song = song.getSong();

                         }



                         Current_Song = song.getSong();



                         ImageView IVP_P = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.P_PImage);





                         //If mediaPlayer is paused.

                         if (IsPaused) {

                             P_and_P.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_48dp);

                             //If the song paused is same as the new song.

                             if (Current_Song == Old_Song) {



                                 mediaplayer.start();

                             }



                             //If the song Paused is not the new song.

                             else {

                                 if (mediaplayer != null) {

                                     mediaplayer.release();

                                     mediaplayer = null;

                                 }



                                 int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);



                                 if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {

                                     mediaplayer = mediaplayer.create(SongsListActivity.this, song.getSong());

                                     Old_Song = song.getSong();

                                     NameD.setText(song.getNameOfSong());

                                     RateD.setText(song.getDeveloperRate());

                                     ImageD.setImageResource(song.getImage());

                                     mediaplayer.start();

                                     mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                                         @Override

                                         public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                                             P_and_P.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_48dp);

                                             IsPaused = true;

                                         }

                                     });

                                 }

                             }

                             IsPaused = false;



                         } else if (mediaplayer != null) {

                             //If mediaPlayer is already Playing a song.

                             if (mediaplayer.isPlaying()) {

                                 P_and_P.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_48dp);

                                 mediaplayer.pause();

                                 IVP_P.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp);

                                 IsPaused = true;

                             }

                         }



                         //If mediaPlayer is used for first time and if mediaPlayer is neither paused

                         else {



                             if (mediaplayer != null) {

                                 mediaplayer.release();

                                 mediaplayer = null;

                             }



                             int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);



                             if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {

                                 mediaplayer = mediaplayer.create(SongsListActivity.this, song.getSong());

                                 Old_Song = song.getSong();

                                 NameD.setText(song.getNameOfSong());

                                 RateD.setText(song.getDeveloperRate());

                                 ImageD.setImageResource(song.getImage());

                                 mediaplayer.start();

                                 P_and_P.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_48dp);



                                 mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                                     @Override

                                     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                                         P_and_P.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_48dp);

                                         IsPaused = true;

                                         P_and_P.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_48dp);



                                     }

                                 });

                             }

                         }



                     }



             }

            );
```

Now, whenever the execution enters into any if the onCompletion() method, i want want the execution to start execution from beginning of the onItemClick() method.

What should I do?

For being more detailed:-

Here my app displays a list of songs using ListView and Adapter. The details of songs are stored in a arrayList(As You All Can See).When an item is clicked, it gets the position of that item, then refers to the corresponding element of the arrayList, gets the location of the corresponding song and then plays that song. What I want is that when an song is over, and the method onCompletion() is called, I want to increase to value of i(look in the 4th line of my code) by one and then go to the first line of the onItemClick method.

Comment: You have to click an Item :)

Comment: I don't want to do it by clicking an item, i want executor to automatically go to beginning. Like what happens with goto and label.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is called a GOTO and is widely regarded as bad design. Instead, extract the code you want to call into a method and call that from both(all) places where you want it to execute.

Comment: I know that using goto is a very bad approach, but in my case goto will perform the task in a more better way than a method. Can you please tell me how can I use it here? Please!

Comment: Try https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java+goto+how+to
Basically, you declare a label: `label:` and then later you use the goto keyword: `goto label;`. Have fun with your spaghetti code!

EDIT: To clarify, I'd advise changing your entire design before even thinking about using GOTOs.

Comment: goto keyword is not supported by java

Comment: Ya. I just no found it out. The site also told me that I can use continue label instead of goto label.

Comment: @NoOne you are right, I was thinking of `continue label;`